# Azure Data Factory - Pagination Rules

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity that pulls data from an API which has pagination.... I have seen many examples online of using numbered pagination, but the API I'm working with uses ID based pagination.

Here is an example of the response headers in postman

[image]

When I configure ADF pagination rules to be RFC5988, it only does the first request, bringing back 200 users. If I set up no pagination rules, it does the same... I haven't tried QueryParameters because all the examples I found online use integer-based pagination.

Is there a way to bring back more than 200 uses without some complicated extraction of the rel="next" and building logic to loop through that? It just seems like this is a pretty standard pagination process, so I'm surprised it won't work out-of-box

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I too am trying to pull Users for an RFC5988 data source and have the same issue.

Comment: No I built a custom loop/solution :\